# CI_Session Files Driver (PHP error Encountered)

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, xampp

> Fatal error: Class CI_Session_files_driver contains 1 abstract method
>   and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining
>   methods (SessionHandlerInterface::read) in
>   \Session\drivers\Session_files_driver.php on line 49
>
> A PHP Error was encountered Severity: Error Message: Class
>   CI_Session_files_driver contains 1 abstract method and must therefore
>   be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods
>   (SessionHandlerInterface::read) Filename:
>   drivers/Session_files_driver.php Line Number: 49 Backtrace:

PHP 7.0.8
Codeigniter 3.0.6
XAMPP 7

Have been using an older version of Codeigniter, XAMPP and PHP 5 for almost 2 years, and has never encountered this issue.

This started occurring intermittently after upgrading CI,XAMPP,PHP. Opcache is disabled as well.

Any thoughts?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: did you read this? https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/installation/upgrade_300.html#step-6-update-your-session-library-usage

Comment: There seems to be a problem with PHP v7 and XAMPP on certain platforms. Read the following thread on the [CodeIgniter Forum](https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-64849.html). It's unclear to me that there is a solution.

Comment: @DFriend have been through that thread already. The only option left to test is to downgrade back to PHP 5.

Comment: @Vickel - have gone through that installation process while upgrading. The only part left out is the adding the save session path which was left out on purpose, so no data is stored any where and instead it uses session.

Comment: You should consider using Virtualbox or VMWare as alternatives to XAMPP or WAMP. I set up a LAMP stack using Virtualbox and am having no problems with PHP7 and CI 3.1.6