# Class CI session files driver contains 1 abstract method and must be therefore declared abstract or implement the remaining methods

Tags: php, codeigniter

PHP version - 7.0.8
CI version - 3.0.6
XAMPP

Once I restart XAMPP, it goes off but it occurs after some time. It looks like when there are more users accessing (more load), it occurs, but not sure.

System folder files haven't been changed. It's still the same. Have been running older version of PHP, CI for almost 2 years and didn't come across this issue. After upgrading CI and php intermittently the following occurs:

```
Fatal error: Class CI Session files drivers contain 1 abstract method and must
therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (
SessionHandlerInterface::read) in system\libraries\Session\drivers\
Session_files_driver.php on line 49

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error
Message: Class CI_Session_files_driver contains 1 abstract method and must
therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (
SessionHandlerInterface::read)

Filename: drivers/Session_files_driver.php
LineNumber:49
Backtrace:
```

If you could please let me know a solution that will be really great.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42503240/intermittent-php-abstract-class-error

Comment: someone just asked this question a bit earlier.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47019697/ci-session-files-driver-php-error-encountered. Are you the same person (@Leo)?